# How to connect or make relation between two OFFLINE Parse objects?

Tags: android, parse-platform, offline

I have problem with Parse. I'm making something like Shopping List App and I can't find solution. Here is the problem:
I have clean app without connection to internet yet, but will be. I'm making offline shopping lists now so I'm creating list and pin to local database like this:

```
ParseObject list = new ParseObject("ShoppingList");
                list.put("name", listNameString);
                list.put("status", "0");
                list.put("deadline",textDate.getText().toString());
                list.pinInBackground();
```

Objects offline do not have ID.
Next I'm trying to add some products to this in next activity.
I have object of ShoppingList and new product and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
        saveProductB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ParseObject product = new ParseObject("ProductOfList");
            product.put("name", productName.getText().toString());
            product.put("status", "0"); //status wykupienia produktu
            product.put("amount", productAmount.getText().toString());
            product.put("category", productCategory.getSelectedItem().toString());
            product.put("description", productDescription.getText().toString());
            product.put("measure", productMeasure.getSelectedItem().toString());
            product.put("icon", productIcon.getText().toString());
            product.put("belongsToOffline", list);
            product.pinInBackground();

            Intent intent = new Intent(AddProductToList.this,ShoppingListDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("LIST_OBJECT", list);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

but without unique ID I have no possibility to get object with this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ProductOfList");
    query.fromLocalDatastore();
    query.whereEqualTo("belongsToOffline",list);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(ParseObject s : scoreList){


                }
                Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

with `list.get("name")` instead of `list` inside `belongsToOffline` everything is ok but I need to let user to make various lists with the same name.
Any solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Once go with this URL : http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#the-local-datastore

Comment: ok. I tried this a lot of times and everything is ok. My problem is that i want to make relation of two different objects which don't have ID. Do I need to make my own id for this object?